# Using absolute path in our private Node dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, module, yarnpkg, es6-modules

I've split out our codebase's React components into a private dependency so that the components can be used by different projects. The components all use Webpack aliases to make the code much more readable:

```
import TestComponent from 'components/TestComponent';
```

Rather than:

```
import TestComponent from '../../components/TestComponent';
```

Now the components have been removed from the project with the Webpack alias setup, so the aliases have naturally stopped working.

The new project that I am building and attempting to import these components in is done as follows:

```
Wrapper project, a Vite development project importing the components library.
>> Components imported as a dependency named 'core'
>>> All of the included React components are using the absolute paths.
```

I'm really stuck on finding out if there's a way to alias imports **in the dependency itself.** The issue is that my file `/views/TestView` is attempting to import `/components/shared/Button` and only works if I use a relative path:

### /views/TestView.jsx

```
import Button from '../components/shared/Button'
```

So unless I do a huge refactor across many hundreds of components to change the absolute paths to relative paths, is there any way to alias the path in a dependency?

A possible solution (not tried yet) might be to further split the components down into specific category dependencies, for example:

- **core** - A package.json containing ALL of the following dependencies
- **@core/views**
- **@core/components**

Any help or ideas on how to achieve this (if it's even possible) would be massively appreciated. Anything to avoid a massive refactor and the eyesore of having to use relative paths in every file.

Comment: npm link? https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557

Comment: I've already linked the components library, but the difficulty is that I am trying to avoid using relative paths in the same dependency calling other files in the same dep

Comment: if you use npm link then you don't need relative paths. just add the package like any other npm package

Comment: I am trying to call files in one dependency only (node_modules/myModule/views/View.jsx is trying to call node_modules/myModule/components/Button.jsx)

Comment: how are you compiling the components library?

Comment: I'm not, the components dep is just a folder containing JSX components. The idea was that the project that imports them would do all of the compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I instead opted for having one core module that had all of the separate folders included as dependencies. This meant that I could call the code like so:

```
import Component from 'components/button'
```

has now been changed to use the dependencies from the core module so that it looks like:

```
import Component from '@core/components/button'
```